# BadFieldException[ Cache must be enabled for nativelib or installer-desc support,http

Tags: java, swing, jnlp

I was looking for answer to fix this issue and couldn't find anything, so just posting it with answer for others.

If you try to open JAVA desktop application and get "
BadFieldException[ Cache must be enabled for nativelib or installer-desc support,http" exception.

Answer (score 12):

Follow below steps..

- Open Java Setting
- Click the Settings button under "Temporary Internet Files" on the General tab.
- Make sure the check box "Keep temporary files on my computer" is marked.

  (Everything else will grey out if it isn't.)